# Illegalstateexception: getwriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, pdf

I am trying to open pdf file in browser using the following code snippet:

```
    public ActionResult action(Request request, AspectModel arg1)
        throws ServletException {
    if ("PDF".equals(request.event())) {
    try{
    HttpServletResponse resp=(HttpServletResponse) request.getResponse();
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=AccountOpeningSummary.pdf");
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "cache, must-revalidate");
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store,public");
    resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    resp.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    OutputStream OutStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    OutStream.write(infos,0,infos.length);
    OutStream.flush();        
    OutStream.close(); 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("PDF Write Exception...........................####"+e);
    }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:215)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flush(JspWriterImpl.java:177)
    at abaxx.web.taglib.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:69)
    at org.apache.jsp.parts.index_jsp._jspx_meth_xx_005finclude_005f0(index_jsp.java:237)
    at org.apache.jsp.parts.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at abaxx.core.foundation.internal.SelfDestroyingHttpServletRequestWrapper$1.include(SelfDestroyingHttpServletRequestWrapper.java:36)
    at abaxx.core.foundation.internal.SelfDestroyingHttpServletRequestWrapper$1.include(SelfDestroyingHttpServletRequestWrapper.java:36)
    at abaxx.web.parts.internal.ServletRequestContext.doInclude(ServletRequestContext.java:85)
    at abaxx.web.parts.RequestContext.include(RequestContext.java:429)
    at abaxx.web.parts.VisualPart.basicDisplay(VisualPart.java:740)
    at abaxx.web.parts.CompositePart.basicDisplay(CompositePart.java:111)
    at abaxx.web.parts.VisualPart.doDisplay(VisualPart.java:762)
    at abaxx.web.control.DisplayLoopInterceptor.display(DisplayLoopInterceptor.java:233)
    at abaxx.web.security.StandardSecurityPolicy$DisplayHook.display(StandardSecurityPolicy.java:321)
    at abaxx.web.control.PerformanceMonitor$DisplayPerformanceInterceptor.display(PerformanceMonitor.java:187)
    at abaxx.web.control.DisplayLoopInterceptor.doDisplay(DisplayLoopInterceptor.java:80)
    at abaxx.web.parts.VisualPart.display(VisualPart.java:104)
    at abaxx.web.control.DisplayLoopInterceptor.process(DisplayLoopInterceptor.java:128)
    at vanilla.portal.builder.PBDisplayLoopInterceptor.process(PBDisplayLoopInterceptor.java:60)
    at vanilla.common.EncodingExtension$ResponseEncodingInterceptor.process(EncodingExtension.java:107)
    at abaxx.web.preferences.PreferencesHookup$2.process(PreferencesHookup.java:126)
    at vanilla.common.HttpHeaderInterceptor.process(HttpHeaderInterceptor.java:36)
    at abaxx.web.control.PageflowInterceptor.process(PageflowInterceptor.java:62)
    at abaxx.workflow.pageflow.PageflowInterceptor.process(PageflowInterceptor.java:93)
    at abaxx.web.control.ActionInterceptor.process(ActionInterceptor.java:49)
    at abaxx.web.security.StandardSecurityPolicy$ActionHook.process(StandardSecurityPolicy.java:211)
    at abaxx.web.control.SessionTimeoutInterceptor.process(SessionTimeoutInterceptor.java:59)
    at abaxx.track.TrackingInterceptor.finishTracking(TrackingInterceptor.java:151)
    at abaxx.track.TrackingInterceptor.process(TrackingInterceptor.java:100)
    at abaxx.web.control.AccessViolationInterceptor.process(AccessViolationInterceptor.java:110)
    at abaxx.web.control.RequestProcessor$P9.process(RequestProcessor.java:72)
    at abaxx.web.control.PerformanceMonitor$RequestPerformanceInterceptor.process(PerformanceMonitor.java:153)
    at vanilla.common.EncodingExtension$RequestEncodingInterceptor.process(EncodingExtension.java:61)
    at abaxx.web.control.MaintenanceInterceptor.process(MaintenanceInterceptor.java:44)
    at abaxx.web.control.AbaXXComponentsHookup$ClientSessionHookupInterceptor.process(AbaXXComponentsHookup.java:42)
    at abaxx.web.security.SecurityPolicy$FakeContainerLoginInterceptor.process(SecurityPolicy.java:136)
    at abaxx.web.control.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:187)
    at abaxx.web.control.ApplicationServlet.doGet(ApplicationServlet.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at abaxx.web.control.url.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at abaxx.web.control.CachingHeaderFilter.doFilter(CachingHeaderFilter.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at vanilla.common.EncodingExtension.doFilter(EncodingExtension.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I have also tried by closing the `getWriter()`
using:

```
HttpServletResponse resp=(HttpServletResponse) request.getResponse();
Writer rt=resp.getWriter();
resp.getWriter().close();
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of abaxx are you using? In recent versions you can return ActionResult.ABORT from the action method if you genereate the response in the controller. 
If you return null the framework will proceed to the display-phase and render the JSP.

Comment: In 8.5 your code should work if you change the last line of your action mehtod from `return null` to `return abaxx.web.aspects.ActionResult.ABORT`

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV Could you solve your problem with the IllegalStateException ?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Now that the question has changed significantly...

It sounds like the JSP is still trying to render itself as the response. You need to tell the container that you're handling the request - ideally you shouldn't go anywhere near a JSP, as this is presumably a request *just* for the PDF. You should configure the container to call a separate servlet to download the PDF; that way you won't get the JSP part involved at all.

(And yes, that will mean moving the code you've shown in the question. That's presumably currently part of a JSP; it shouldn't be.)

Comment: separate window to download the PDF can be provided as:- resp.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename=sample.pdf");          But i need to display the pdf in thw jsp itself..

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV: It's not clear what you mean by "display the pdf in the jsp itself", but you can't serve both the PDF and the HTML in the same response. You *may* be able to embed a PDF viewer somehow, but fundamentally a request is *either* going to have an HTML response *or* a PDF response.

Comment: @ Jon my aim is to display the pdf in the browser itself.

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV: That still doesn't mean it should be rendered *as part of a JSP response*. I don't know exactly which headers you'll need to supply in order to do that (rather than downloading) but it'll still be a separate response which *only* contains the PDF.

Comment: @ Jon Sorry,I don't really get the point you are mentioning. From my understanding,the error comes due to the clash between PrintWriter and OutputStreamWriter.

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV: No, the error comes because you've got two pieces of code trying to write into the same response: the JSP, and the code you've posted. The response can only contain *one* thing: HTML from the JSP *or* the PDF contents.

Comment: @BalusC: I'm still interested in your answer to my question. Is this answer hopelessly off-track, and if so, how? Obviously I'd want to delete it if so.

Comment: @ Jon I'm using the abaxx framework. Can you give your answer specific to that framework ?

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV: Nope, I've never even heard of it. But apply the *principles* of my answer to that framework - they should translate without too much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you've put that PDF generating code which uses the response output stream in a JSP file by `<jsp:include>`. JSP files implicitly use the response writer because JSP files are designed to generate HTML code which is character based (and not binary based like PDF files). JSP is in first place the wrong place to put PDF generating code in. HTML and PDF don't mix very well.

To solve your design problem, you need to create a simple class extending `HttpServlet`, move all that Java code into the `doGet()` method (or `doPost()`, depending on what kind of requests you'd like to respond on). Finally map that servlet on a desired URL pattern by `@WebServlet` annotation or `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml` and change the URL of the PDF request from the JSP one to the servlet one.

Here's a basic kickoff example assuming that you're using a Servlet 3.0 compatible container such as Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, etc so that you can use `@WebServlet` annotation:

```
@WebServlet("/pdfServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Put your code here.
    }

}
```

Invoke it by `http://localhost:8080/contextname/pdfServlet` instead of `index.jsp`.

---

If your requirement is after all to present the PDF inline in a HTML page, then you need `<iframe>` instead of `<jsp:include>`. E.g.

```html
<iframe src="pdfServlet"></iframe>
```

This way the browser will download the PDF file by an entirely separate HTTP request.

Comment: it is not done in JSP. It is done inside a java class(the controller class)

Comment: The stacktrace indicates otherwise. Perhaps you're submitting the form to the JSP instead of directly to the servlet.

Comment: @ BalusC i'm using an actioncontroller class (in the abaxx framework) same as the servlet and it has the method ActionResult action(Request request, AspectModel model) which is similar to doGet.

Comment: You should not invoke it by `<jsp:include>`.

Comment: @ Balusc I'm not using  <jsp:include>
In my jsp page there is a button and the buttonclick will lead to  ActionResult action(Request request, AspectModel model)

Comment: Again, the stacktrace indicates otherwise. Look at around those lines: `at abaxx.web.taglib.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:69)`. This shouldn't have appeared in the stacktrace at all. Replace exactly that tag by an `<iframe>`.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you need to replace that server side include tag by an `<iframe>`.

Comment: @ BalusC I'm using the abaxx framework. So can you modify your answer in that way.